# how to add php to javascript that is within php

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I have a page of PHP code.

I have then added facebook comments in javascript:

```
$output = '<div id="fb-root"> ... </div>';
```

WITHIN this `$output` I would like to add a call to a PHP function `drupal_mail()`.

The code looks like:

```
$output = '<div id="fb-root"> ....
FB.Event.subscribe("comment.create", function (response) {
'. drupal_mail("facebook_comments", "notify", "xxx.com",               user_preferred_language($user), $params); .  '
</div>';
```

but I'm getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'`

How do I add the `drupal_mail()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You have `;` after `user_preferred_language` function call, you just need to remove that.

Comment: then I just get the error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' '

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible for execute a server side operation in client side event in way above. You must be send request back to server ( using ajax preferable ).

```
$output = '<div id="fb-root"> ....
FB.Event.subscribe("comment.create", function (response) {
// Put some ajax code here to send request to php with data
</div>';**strong text**
```

Use server side code to catch ajax request and then send email

```
function send_email()
{
     drupal_mail("facebook_comments", "notify", "xxx.com",                        user_preferred_language($user), $params);
}
```

Comment: My issue is that I'm a php programmer and I don't really know how to program with ajax so I keep making mistakes. Could you give me an example of some ajax code I could use? Thanks

Comment: For sample ajax code See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G8rLW/ Where you can put your domain and request page. Also I send arguments through json. You have to check out that how you can manage this in drupal for GET arguments and then you can send mail through drupal_mail.

Comment: I've added your sample ajax code I replaced url: 'http://yourdomain.com/your_request_page' with the path to my mail.php file or should it be the file where the ajax code is? also xxx.com - should this be the same as url path above or just my site address?

Comment: your request page uri should be the php which called drupal_mail function. xxx.com is same as you passed into your drupal_mail function as I am assuming you are sending this argument through client side. If that is not the case you can ignore that argument.

Comment: I wrote it as $.ajax({type: "POST",
 url: "//xxx.com/mail.php", 
       success: function() {
                alert("Request Sent.");
            }
     }); but it still isn't working. What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure I understood what you wrote 'I send arguments through json' Is type:POST ok?